# How to get Node from XML without considering namespace name in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am writing a java program in which I am parsing input xml file which looks like this:

```
...
<ems:DeterminationRequest>
    <ems:MessageInformation>
       <ns17:MessageID xmlns:ns17="http://www.calheers.ca.gov/EHITSAWSInterfaceCommonSchema">1000225404</ns17:MessageID>
       <ns17:MessageTimeStamp xmlns:ns17="http://www.calheers.ca.gov/EHITSAWSInterfaceCommonSchema">2015-07-28T01:17:04</ns17:MessageTimeStamp>
       <ns17:SendingSystem xmlns:ns17="http://www.calheers.ca.gov/EHITSAWSInterfaceCommonSchema">CH</ns17:SendingSystem>
       <ns17:ReceivingSystem xmlns:ns17="http://www.calheers.ca.gov/EHITSAWSInterfaceCommonSchema">LD</ns17:ReceivingSystem>
       <ns17:ServicingFipsCountyCode xmlns:ns17="http://www.calheers.ca.gov/EHITSAWSInterfaceCommonSchema">037</ns17:ServicingFipsCountyCode>
    </ems:MessageInformation>
</ems:DeterminationRequest>
...
```

Now I am trying to get node "ems:MessageInformation" without considering namespace name "ems". So I tried following lines of code:

```
Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\test.xml")));
Node element = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagNameNS("*","MessageInformation").item(0);
System.out.println(element.getNodeName());
```

But it's giving Null Pointer exception because function is not reading required node. I gone through this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagNameNS%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for reference. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an odd/buggy behaviour in den `NodeList` implementation returned by

`doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagNameNS("*","MessageInformation")`

It allows you to access `item(0)` **but** returns a null object.
(If you are using a current JDK the `NodeList` implementation is `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl` which lazily loads its items and shows this buggy behaviour).

---

To prevent the `NullPointerException` you should first check if the returned `NodeList` has a length > 0:

```
NodeList result = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagNameNS("*","MessageInformation");
if (result.getLength() > 0) {
    Node element = (Element)result.item(0);
    ...
}
```

---

Then you need to find out why `getElementsByTagNameNS` does not return the element.

One possible reason could be that you parsed the document without namespace support. The consequence is that the dom elements don't have namespace information and `getElementsByTagNameNS` fails.

To turn on namespace support use:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

Alternatively without namespace support you could search for

```
NodeList nl = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("ems:MessageInformation");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response :). "DocumentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);" this change has worked for me.